# Some assistance with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a little project and need a consult on some functionality I am trying to implement.

I've tried using Unions & Sub-selects to achieve this but I've had no joy.

The data set is as follows:

1. There are 25 kids in a classroom and each of the kids in the
   classroom have 3 classes in common namely:

   1.2 English

   1.3 Maths

   1.4 Science
2. These kids also have 5 other classes they do not have in common which could range from the following:

(Computer Science, Life Science, Geography, History, Art, etc)

---

I've written this thing in PHP7 & MySQL.. (classic monolithic style)

I need some help drawing a table that will list all available classes and spew out all the kids in the DB with that class attribute under the respective table head.

Anyone have an idea of how I could achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

having two tables Kids, Classes with a relation many to many will give you the flexibility to query about the kids' classes it will be like:

### Kids_classes_table:

Kids_id, class_id, grade, first_exam, second ... ext

you can control the mandatory classes by adding a flag to the classes' table and check it in PHP code,

---

Hope this will help